# An error occurred while loading 'com.companyname.APPNAME.apk' : but the error could not be deserialized

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play, apk

I am trying to get my apk file to publish my xamarin.forms app on google play but i am getting this error and i have no clue what is wrong.

The first part is in french but it says : An error occurred while loading 'com.companyname.APPNAME.apk' : but the error could not be deserialized.

If the error cannot be deserialized, it's kinda hard to know whats wrong.. Plus the last time i did this, everything went well.
I am following these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows#newcert

Any idea ? thanks

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that message, but given that this worked before, I would first try starting over:  Close Visual Studio.  Delete any `bin` and `obj` files - to be certain that EVERYTHING gets rebuilt. Rebuild Solution (or rt-click on project / Rebuild) - to make sure the build process succeeded, before we get into the archive step. (To make sure we know exactly when something goes wrong.)  Now make the archive. Do you get the error while making the archive? Or only when you try to distribute or use it?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for reply, the error happens at the end of the distribution

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Deleted obj file and did what u said and i still get this error..

Comment: Sorry, I was just guessing that might work, based on different problems that could be fixed that way. Are you storing sources online (github or similar)?  If so, try checking the repository out to a new location (so that you know it is a "clean build"), and rebuilding it there. Given that this worked before, I suspect something has gotten "corrupted".